# Explicitly extending Object class and calling clone method of object throwing error

Tags: java

i tried the following code for cloning the object. while compiling it shows clone is protected and cannot be accessed, but i had extended Object class, hence the clone method will be public to my class . please explain me the reason.

```
class storeDate extends Object {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    storeDate d = new storeDate();
    Object o = (storeDate)d;
    o.clone():
  }

}
```

while compilation i get this error

clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object
        kkk.clone();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is which package the classes belongs to.

This is explained in [JLS paragraph 6.6.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2):

> ***6.6.2 Details on protected Access***
>   *A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared **only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object**.*

---

Examples:

This does **not compile**:

**FILE pkg1/A.java** (corresponds to the Object class in your question)

```
package pkg1;
public class A {
    protected void method() {};
}
```

**FILE pkg2/B.java** (corresponds to storeDate in your question)

```
package pkg2;
import pkg1.A;
public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A().method();
    }
}
```

`javac` outputs the following:

```
pkg2/B.java:5: method() has protected access in pkg1.A
        new A().method();
               ^
```

(which is similar to what you have: *clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object kkk.clone();*)

---

Simply moving `B` to the `pkg1` package solves it.

That is, this **does** compile:

**FILE pkg1/A.java** (unchanged)

```
package pkg1;
public class A {
    protected void method() {};
}
```

**FILE pkg1/B.java** (moved from pkg2 to pkg1)

```
package pkg1;                 // Changed from pkg2
//import pkg1.A;              // Not necessary anymore.
public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A().method();
    }
}
```

---

So, what would have been required for you to be able to do something like `new Object().clone()`? Well, you would have to belong to the `java.lang` package (which in turn, however results in a `SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang`).

Answer (score 1):

You should override and implement the clone method from Object. Then you can call `clone()` or `super.clone()` if you need the method body from `Object.clone`. The standard implementation just clones primitive types and references to other objects.

And the subclass needs to implement the interface `Cloneable` (which is just a marker interface with no methods to implement).

---

(Back to your question) Object itself is not cloneable (doesn't implement Cloneable) and thus can't be cloned. And because `Object#clone` is implemented as a protected method, any subclass of `Object` (= every class in fact) can access its inherited `clone()` method and every class inside the 'java.lang`package can access`clone()` methods from other objects too.

For a quick understanding of modifiers see this [nice matrix](http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javaprotection.php).

Comment: ok. But super.clone() won't do it since he wants to do "thatOtherObject.clone()"? or did I misunderstand something? :\

Comment: @Andreas_D  since i extend Object class  the protected member will be public to the subclass . so i can cast to object type and call Object's clone method without overriding.

Comment: @Andreas_D while compiling i get this error 

clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object
        kkk.clone();

Comment: ... sorry, I was still editing and improving the answer - the first 'release' wasn't actually good and helpful

Comment: But why does this work then: `class A { protected void hello() {} } public class B extends A { public static void main(String args[]) { new B().hello(); } }` ?

Comment: @aioobe - you're right and I hope my actual answer is much better - the `thatOtherObject.clone()` will require overriding the clone() method and declaring the overriding method as `public`.

Comment: @aioobe - because a subclass has access to protected methods of it's superclass !?

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) I mixing up the situation with something similar. Sorry!

Comment: I actually don't think this answer explains the issue really. See my answer.

Comment: The matrix "does" explain it: "Class SubB has access only to the inherited from Base protected elements, i.e. its own elements, but the protected data of other Base instances is not accessible from SubB."

Comment: Sure. The link to the matrix explains it, but this answer does not even mention the word "package".

Comment: 13 comments plus this one so far, how many more to get a badge? :-))

Comment: package java.lang results in SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

Comment: (that's what I expected - thanks for mentioning it, I don't have an IDE at hand, maybe I have a look at it tonight, if there's a way around this 'issue' :-) )

Comment: The SystemClassloader has hardcoded security checks if the package name of a class starts with 'java' (although java accepts the java.* packages in rt.jar... ;) ) inside final methods. Apart from 'patching' classes in rt.jar - no chance adding a class to the java.lang package. Thanks for making me learn something new ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely have to use `clone`? Most people agree that Java's `clone` is broken.

[Josh Bloch on Design - Copy Constructor versus Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you read between the lines, you will know that I think `clone` is deeply broken. [...] It's a shame that `Cloneable` is broken, but it happens.

You may read more discussion on the topic in his book *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 11: Override `clone` judiciously*. He recommends instead to use a copy constructor or copy factory.

He went on to write pages of pages on how, if you feel you must, you should implement `clone`. But he closed with this:

> Is all this complexities really necessary? Rarely. If you extend a class that implements `Cloneable`, you have little choice but to implement a well-behaved `clone` method. Otherwise, **you are better off providing alternative means of object copying, or simply not providing the capability**.

The emphasis was his, not mine. The entire item is a must read to understand the issues deeper and to consider alternatives.

#### Related questions

- [Why is the clone() method protected in java.lang.Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object)
- [Why people are so afraid of using clone() (on collection and JDK classes) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes)
- [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method)

---

#### So how to copy objects?

Here's a quote from the book:

> **A fine approach to object copying is to provide a copy constructor or copy factory**.

In this case, it can be implemented simply with providing a `StoreDate` constructor that takes another `StoreDate`, or providing a utility method `static StoreDate newInstanceFrom(StoreDate other)`.

#### Related questions

- [clone() vs copy constructor vs factory method??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method)

Comment: You're avoiding the question. The answer is that it has to do with the fact that storeDate and Object belong to different packages.