# Create in a simple way a copy of an object

Tags: java

Consider the code below:

```
Project project1 = new Project("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5", ...);
Project project2 = project1;
```

Here, `project2` is not a copy of `project1`, because it points to the same object.
It significate that if I edit `project2`, it also edit `project1`.

I want `project2` to be independent of `project1`.
I suppose that I can make a constructor with a `Project` param like:

```
public Project(Project project) {
    this.string1 = project.getString1();
    this.string2 = project.getString2();
    ...
}
```

I my case, I have something like 15 attributes in my Project class, so doing this would require me to write a big constructor.

Is there a better way to do this ? :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a better way to do that. You could use `clone`, but... don't. [Don't use `clone`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128281/if-clone-for-arraylist-is-broken-why-cant-they-fix-it)

Comment: Really ? :/
With smart classes it is quiet good, but with big classes, it could be very long ...

Comment: @Mistalis Yes, that's correct. That's one reason why you shouldn't create gigantic classes.

Comment: I know big classes is a bad idea, but in my case, I didn't find a way to do something better :-D
I will make a constructor by copy so ...

Comment: @Mistalis http://stackoverflow.com/a/3333989/1080648 may be relevant to avoid the manual copying of attributes, although read the linked articles carefully to make sure it's right for your setup

Comment: @JonStory Using reflection for this is going to be very, very slow. I would say that, any time you have a class so big that you're considering using reflection to loop through its attributes when copying it, that's a sign that you have some refactoring to do.