# Create object clone via database read vs cloning

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, clone

The need to create an object clone came up at some point in our project and having heard that interfaces such as `Cloneable` and the like aren't really the best thing to use so as a fast solution I thought of just querying the database to receive a copy of that object (the moment the cloning happens is right after an `upsert` statement). Then I also thought of a hacky clone method using object serialization-deserialization. What would you choose?

Note that I am using MongoDB as a repository with Spring Data and in the future we are thinking of adding Spring's Caching mechanism in our repositories.

Comment: Why not a copy constructor?

Comment: The object has many fields that are other types which in turn have other types, many are Collections etc. If I implement a copy constructor I might as well implement a clone method. Also copy constructors are error prone to field additions.

Comment: Then I would get the copy from the database querying it as you suggest. Why not clone? -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/2599165/4751165