# Is it possible to .clone() a List in Java?

Tags: java

I get an error on the line where I set `this.pastMoves = pastMoves.clone()`

I think that you can clone an ArrayList but maybe not a List? I'm not too sure but it does not want to clone.

This class is a part of a program to find the shortest path a knight can make on a chessboard from one location to another. I need to spawn new knights off of older moves and pass the old moves on as well as add a new one. If I do not clone the list then all separate moves will add on to one large list, but I need different paths to save separately.

```java
import java.util.List;

/*
 * This class is for the knight which holds information
 * on its previous moves and its current move
 */
public class Knight {
        
    private List<int[]> pastMoves;
    private int[] currentLocation;
    
    public Knight(List<int[]> pastMoves, int[] currentMove) {
        this.pastMoves = pastMoves.clone();
        pastMoves.add(currentMove);
        currentLocation = currentMove;
    }
    
    public List<int[]> getPastMoves(){
        return pastMoves;
    }
    
    public int[] getCurrentLocation() {
        return currentLocation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly possible to *copy* a `List`, but `clone()` is, in general, an ill-advised language feature you should never use.

To do a shallow copy of a `List`, just write e.g. `new ArrayList<>(list)`, which uses the `ArrayList` copy constructor.

To do a deep copy of a `List`, you should be manually copying each element over to a new `List`, probably an `ArrayList`, using the appropriate means of deep copying that element type.

Comment: Thank you! If you dont mind me asking, why is .clone() ill advised?

Comment: [Why people are afraid of using clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2597965/3890632)

Comment: @JonathonFord  The concept is great, the design if flawed.