# How to clone array in java with this code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This code generates unsorted array. My question is how do I clone the generated array so I can reuse the unsorted array in different sorting algorithms.

public class UnsortedData{

```
private int [] coreData;
private int maxArraySize;
private int currentArraySize;

public UnsortedData(int size){
    this.maxArraySize = size;
    this.coreData = new int[this.maxArraySize];
    this.currentArraySize = 0;
}

public boolean addData(int data){
    if (currentArraySize < maxArraySize)
    {
        coreData[currentArraySize] = data;
        currentArraySize++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

public class dataSorting {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    UnsortedData uD = new UnsortedData(1000000);

    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        uD.addData(rand.nextInt(3000000));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use build in methods from **java.lang.Object** to clone the original array and **java.util.Arrays** to sort the cloned array.

```
int[] arr = {6,9,4,5};            // original array
int[] arrCopy = arr.clone()       // we created a copy of the array

Arrays.sort(arrCopy);             // it sort the array that we cloned
```

References: [Arrays Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) , [Class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way? Object.clone()

```
int[] arr = coreData.clone();
```

You can also use the Stream API or external libraries such as Apache Commons.

Comment: You need to see why [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes) is not a good idea